# Implementing sbs 3D on Vuforia+Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, android-augmented-reality

I am new to augmented reality.

I have been going through several tutorials, but I do not see them showing a way to create a side-by-side stereoscopic view for AR apps on android.

How can I implement it? Please help, let me know if there are any tutorials on this.

An implementation of SBS 3D

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hello augmented reality with unity can be done with ar foundation , here is a tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mpsiO2lCx0

The side-by-side view is a virtual reality view which can be achieved with cardboard sdk. Here is a tutorial for that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZzhXHqXM-g

Comment: thanks. But what I am asking is how can we create sbs view for augmented reality. Such that I can start the ar app on my android phone and put it on a device like google cardboard or antbox and use it.

Comment: My phone already has a SBS mode, it splits my phone screen in two. However, not all phones have such options.